# It is possible create a layout and view flipper on the same line?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]It is possible create a screen of the following way?

![Screen][2]

When I change of page, the same layout is displayed on every page

Regards

Comment: the slide transition of viewflipper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the FrameLayout. The FrameLayout to allow overlap Views

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the layout is possible:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <ViewFlipper android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   </ViewFlipper>
   <!-- I assumed your layout at the top-left corner is a LinearLayout, otherwise replace it with what you have --> 
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:id="@+id/firstLayout">
   </LinearLayout>
   <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstLayout"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit:**

Your question is a little ambiguous, if you want to just add a `TextView` near the `Layout` element from your layout then add the `TextView` and set it an attribute of `toRightOf`(with some margin to put some gaps). Check the modification in the layout above. If you want the `TextView` to be vertical centered(taking in consideration the height of `Layout`) like in your picture then you could wrap the `Layout` and `TextView` in a `LinearLayout` with (width and height set to `wrap_content`) and aligned to top and left in the parent `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same. But on this case: I need set textview to side of layout (on the same line)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really clear, but I suspect what you're looking for is exactly what Kursprog gave you, except that you want to put the top left layout and the text view into a wrapper Linear layout, so your xml would look like this (minus all the attributes).

```
<RelativeLayout>  <!--Parent -->
   <ViewFlipper/>
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"><!-- wrapper to your two top layouts 
      <LinearLayout/> <!-- whatever layout it is that you're describing in your diagram -->
      <TextView/> <!-- the text view in your diagram -->
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You'll want to give the wrapper a width of fill_parent and set the layout_weight of both inner elements to 1, so that they're distributed evenly on the screen.

Comment: I solved the problem with the FrameLayout. The FrameLayout to allow overlap Views